# webpack 4 in production mode fails compiling typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack

After migrating from webpack 3 to webpack 4 following the [readme](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4/#update-plugins)

my typescript app has a complication error when setting webpack to `mode: production`

the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Object.822 (Tag.tsx:65)
```

Which maps to this line:

```
withExpertFeed(({removeAttribute}) => ({removeAttribute})),
```

this webpack config works:

```
module.exports = merge(common(), {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development', // Set to development
    plugins: [
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'public',
        }, ]),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
            checkSyntacticErrors: false,
            tsconfig: '../web-tsconfig.json',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true,
            },
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    output: {
                        ascii_only: true,
                    },
                },
                parallel: true,
                cache: true,
                sourceMap: true
            }),
        ]
    }
});
```

the same webpack config when I set `mode: production` fails with the above error

Comment: Was there more to the stack trace of the error?  I'm no expert with webpack, but if you publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I'll fiddle with it a bit.

Comment: turns out it was due to some circular dependency between packages in my lerna project.